# Run C# code when button clicked in Blend Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface, blend

**Solved**

I have been looking for a while and couldn't find an answer so I guess it will help few more people.

I have found `blend` is an awesome place to make a nice looking UI.

I have made a simple `button` in Blend from Visual Studio 2015.

The XAML of this button looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="56.471,79.283,54.639,68.382"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    WebRequest request =WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");      
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I click the button I had like it to run the following code for reading URL (which is written in C#)

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
```

I'm pretty new in C# and I'm not sure how to combine a code with XAML file.

If someone can show how to implement it will be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: You should simply be able to just replace `Console.WriteLine("yo man");` with the code you want to run, when the button is pressed. Have you tried this or is there any reason why this wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Hey mate, sorry it was my bad that part of the code just to check if i even know to print message. I tried to insert the readurl thing but im having trouble with `WebClient` even after `using System.Net`

Comment: No need to apologize. Could you edit your question to include any compilation errors you might get when inserting your `WebClient` code?

Comment: I have managed to solve the problems! Thank you mate. edited the code in case people will need. @NikolajDamLarsen

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps im missing something but it doesnt appear to be wired up.

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="56.471,79.283,54.639,68.382" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Then in the code behind

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string s = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The wiring has probably been handled in code generated by VS in the `InitializeComponent` method.